# Collect Generic Delegates in a Dictionary

Tags: vb.net, generics, dictionary, delegates

I try to collect generic delegates in a dictionary. I made a little example, knowing that this example doesn't make sense. When I try to add the delegate to the dictionary I get a implizit conversion warning and I don't know how to solve this.

This is the line which shows the warning:

```
m_MyDoSomethings.Add(1, AddressOf myCustomDoSomething)
```

Hint: You have to activate implizit conversion warnings in your project, otherwise you won't get this error. It is a implizit conversion error, which tells me that it is not possible to convert the type "BaseDoSomething" to "CustomDoSomething". I don't understand why he is converting this way and not backwards.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Delegate Sub DoSomethingDelegate(Of T As BaseDoSomething)(p_DoSomethingClass As T)

    Private m_MyDoSomethings As New Dictionary(Of Short, DoSomethingDelegate(Of BaseDoSomething))

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        m_MyDoSomethings.Add(1, AddressOf myCustomDoSomething)

    End Sub

    Private Sub myCustomDoSomething(p_CustomDoSomething As CustomDoSomething)
        p_CustomDoSomething.echo()
        p_CustomDoSomething.echo2()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class BaseDoSomething

    Public Overridable Sub echo()

        MsgBox("echo")

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class CustomDoSomething
    Inherits BaseDoSomething

    Public Overrides Sub echo()

        MsgBox("custom echo")

    End Sub

    Public Sub echo2()

        MsgBox("hello world")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message, and indicate which line of code it's in.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I edited my question. The exakt warning message is "
Warnung BC42016 Implizite Konvertierung von "BaseDoSomething" in "CustomDoSomething".

Comment: Well that's a warning rather than an error. Do you have option strict and option explicit on? Fundamentally there's a problem here, in that you can't treat a `DoSomethingDelegate(CustomDoSomething)` as a `DoSomethingDelegate(BaseDoSomething)` - because the former requires a `CustomDoSomething` parameter, whereas you can invoke the latter with *any* `BaseDoSomething`.

Comment: Yes, I have option strict an explicit turned on. I don't understand why he is converting from Base to Custom and not Backwards. If the sub "myCustomDoSomething" has a parameter with type "BaseDoSomething" it works, but I do need this special type and I don't want to DirectCast it.

Comment: It would have to do this when you *invoke* the delegate, basically... so it's probably creating a delegate by injecting a conversion from `BaseDoSomething` to `CustomDoSomething` before calling the method.

Comment: So, it could be possible that there is no solution for this one if this conversion is within the compiler? I thought generics would be that intelligent...

Comment: Well you're asking for something impossible, basically. You're constructing `DoSomethingDelegate(Of BaseDoSomething)` instances, but those will call methods with parameters of type `CustomDoSomething`. That *has* to involve a conversion that can fail.